# US6108955 A patent seems to be expired

Tags: patent-infringement, us6108955

After doing some more research. The patent us6108955a has expired.  So if that is the case then I should be able to start my company using this system without fear of any legal recourse.  Please tell me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

After a patent has expired anyone may make, use, offer for sale, or sell or import the invention without permission of the patentee, provided that matter covered by other unexpired patents is not used.

There may be more active patents which have same technology with some modification/addition. You need to be careful of such inventions. For example,  if a patent for a simple shoe has expired, you may freely use it(exact technology) to sell your own shoe freely. However you may not sell a shoe with a shock absorber which may be different active patent.